# How to compare with an RGB color in opencv and generate a mask?

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to match against a particular RGB color in opencv and generate a mask where it matches. I tried using `compare()`, but it is operating on the three channels independently. Here's my test program, which I hoped would match against green (00ff00) but it doesn't do that at all.

```
    cv::Mat testImg = cv::imread("test.png", cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
    cv::Mat mask(testImg.size().height, testImg.size().width, CV_8U, cv::Scalar(0));
    cv::compare(testImg, cv::Vec3b(0x00, 0xff, 0x00), mask, cv::CMP_EQ);
    imwrite("out.png", mask);
```

For example, for the input below, I expected the code to match against the green square in the first row:

[image: test pattern with two rows of color squares. Top row uses 0 and ff intensities, while bottom row uses 80 and ff.]

But the output shows that it is matching against 0 on a channel-by-channel basis (and ignoring the 0xff), so the mask ends up with inverted colors (not boolean), which is not at all what I want:

[image: output showing squares of color]

I could `split` the channels, run `compare` three times, and merge the results, but I expect there is a better way. Can I convert the 3-channel image into one 24-bit channel and compare all 24 bits at once? Should I use `inRange`?

Comment: use `inRange()`. since you know of it, why haven't you? :)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz It seems inefficient to do two comparisons when I want to test for equality, so I figured there was probably a better way,.

Comment: might as well threshold against background, get the connected components, evaluate the mean or median or single sample center color of each component. then you've got the entire thing analyzed already. now you can just compare against whatever color values you want. -- converting to a different color space is commonly done but often not necessary or desired. you need not do that. you can work entirely in RGB/BGR. there is no advantage to HSV in your situation that I can see.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cv::inRange` along the `HSV` values of each color to create a binary mask of the color you are looking for. One option is to create a `std::map< std::string, std::vector<cv::Scalar> >` with the color name `string` and a `std::vector` of low and high thresholds. Iterate over the map and create the mask as you go. Something like this (for red, green and blue):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>


int main()
{

    // Read image:
    std::string imagePath = "D://opencvImages//BkxkG.png";
    cv::Mat inputImage = cv::imread(imagePath, cv::IMREAD_COLOR);

    // Convert BGR image to HSV:
    cv::Mat hsvImage;
    cv::cvtColor(inputImage,hsvImage, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV);

    // Dictionary of HSV values:
    std::map< std::string, std::vector<cv::Scalar> > colorDict;

    // Green:
    std::vector<cv::Scalar> colorData = { cv::Scalar( 52, 255, 0 ), cv::Scalar( 67, 255, 255 ) };
    colorDict.emplace("Green", colorData);

    // Red:
    colorData = { cv::Scalar( 0, 185, 0 ), cv::Scalar( 10, 255, 255 ) };
    colorDict.emplace("Red", colorData);

    // Blue:
    colorData = { cv::Scalar( 95, 255, 0 ), cv::Scalar( 130, 255, 255 ) };
    colorDict.emplace("Blue", colorData);

    // Loop through the color dictionary:
    std::map< std::string, std::vector<cv::Scalar> >::iterator it;
    for ( it = colorDict.begin(); it != colorDict.end(); it++ ){

        // Get key:
        std::string currentColor = it->first;

        // Get thresholds:
        std::vector<cv::Scalar> currentThresholds = it->second;
        cv::Scalar lowthreshold = currentThresholds[0];
        cv::Scalar highthreshold = currentThresholds[1];

        // Create HSV mask:
        cv::Mat currentMask;
        cv::inRange(hsvImage, lowthreshold, highthreshold, currentMask);

        std::cout<<"Current Mask: "<<currentColor<<std::endl;
        cv::imshow("CurrentMask", currentMask);
        cv::waitKey(0);

        // AND mask and original input:
        cv::Mat currentColorMask;
        cv::bitwise_and(inputImage, inputImage, currentColorMask, currentMask);
        cv::imshow("currentColorMask", currentColorMask);
        cv::waitKey(0);

    }


    return 0;
}
```

For the blue color you get this binary mask:

[image]

If you `AND` that mask and the original input image you get this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's solving a lot more than I asked for :-)